# How do I make a time delta column in Polars from two datetime columns

Tags: python, duration, timedelta, python-polars

How would I make a column with the delta (in days) of two date columns. I thought I could just subtract the date objects, but I'm obviously missing something

```py
(pl.from_records([{'start': '2021-01-01', 'end': '2022-01-01'}])
 .with_columns(pl.col(['start', 'end']).str.to_date('%Y-%m-%d'))
 .with_columns(delta = pl.col('end') - pl.col('start'))
)
```

Comment: Your code gives a *duration* of `365d` in [`0.18.0`](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/releases/tag/py-0.18.0), *see* : https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2wMC.png.

Comment: Indeed it does, just updated polars on my system. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `Expr.sub()` function instead of the `-` operator:

```
 (pl.from_records([{'start': '2021-01-01', 'end': '2022-01-01'}])
 .with_columns(pl.col(['start', 'end']).str.to_date('%Y-%m-%d'))
 .with_columns(delta = pl.col('end').sub(pl.col('start'))))
```